# How to verify that IPv4 is disabled on a machine?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ipv6, ipv4

Running a 16.04 VM and disabled IPv4 in Network Manager but I'd like a way to verify that IPv4 isn't being used.

Comment: The 'ip', 'ifconfig', and 'route' commands come to mind. They are all terminal commands, installed by default, with manpages.

Comment: @user535733 so when I run ifconfig what am I looking for (or lack thereof)

Comment: lack of `inet` but not the `inet6`